# Checking " / " present or not in variable, if not found add that

Tags: shell

In my script, I am getting a variable MYPATH as a input .

Requirement is, a script to verify that the MYPATH variable contain `/` at the end, if not it should add one:

if `MYPATH=/home/ubuntu`
it should change it to: `MYPATH=/home/ubunt/`

Regards

Comment: What kind of script? bash?

Answer (score 2):

Strip the final /, if present, then re-add one.

```
MYPATH=${MYPATH%/}/
```

This will work in any POSIX-compliant shell. Unfortunately, there's no easy way to remove
multiple trailing slashes in the POSIX shell. You'd have to use a loop:

```
MYPATH=$MYPATH/
# Until removing and adding a single / is a no-op,
# keep stripping the trailing /
until [ "$MYPATH" = "${MYPATH%/}/" ]; do
    MYPATH=${MYPATH%/}
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use parameter expansion to do this.  From the Bash man page:

```
${parameter:offset}
   ${parameter:offset:length}
          Substring  Expansion.   Expands to up to length characters of parameter starting at the character specified by offset.  If length is omitted, expands
          to the substring of parameter starting at the character specified by offset.
${#parameter}
          Parameter length.  The length in characters of the value of parameter is substituted.
```

So, you could do something like this:

```
if [ ${#MYPATH} -gt 0 -a "${MYPATH:${#MYPATH}-1}" != "/" ]; then MYPATH="$MYPATH/"; fi
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot to all for you valuable suggestion . It worked fine for me .

Comment: How to delete some file at the same time using the variable . I tried rm $MYPATHshipper.conf is not working as it taking MYPATHshipper.conf as single value . echo $MYPATH  = /home/ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

If you can use bash, you can strip off any number of characters:

```
shopt -s extglob
echo "${MYPATH%%+(\/)}/"
```

Comment: The `${var/...}` operator is not POSIX.